# docker php how to install event or libevent?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I write a dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-cli

RUN curl -fsSL 'http://pecl.php.net/get/event-2.3.0.tgz' -o event.tgz \
    && mkdir -p event \
    && tar -xf event.tgz -C event --strip-components=1 \
    && rm event.tgz \
    && ( \
        cd event \
        && phpize \
        && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin --with-event-libevent-dir=/usr/local/libevent-2.1.8/ \
        && make -j "$(nproc)" \
        && make install \
    ) \
    && rm -r event \
    && docker-php-ext-enable event
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pcntl \
    #&& pecl install event-2.4.2 \
    #&& docker-php-ext-configure event --with-event-libevent-dir=/usr/local/libevent-2.4.2/ \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pcntl
```

but it no work well.

```
configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH
```

I want use php pecl extensions event or libevent, how should I do? thank you!

Comment: you need to install `php-dev` package that contains this script

Answer (score 2):

The following docker file worked for me:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && apt-get update && apt-get -y install libevent-dev libssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    && pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && pecl install event-2.4.2 && docker-php-ext-enable event \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pcntl mysqli
```

Comment: I removed your question from your answer, if you have another question simply open a new question. Also the other text was not necessary so I removed it.